# Applying apply in Scheme

Tags: scheme, apply

What am I missing here?  I was playing with `apply` in Scheme, and wrote:

```
(apply apply '(+ (1 2 3)))
```

The way I understand it, the first apply should do:

```
(apply + '(1 2 3))
```

and the second should do:

```
(+ 1 2 3)
```

But both Ypsilon and Gauche give about the same error (this is Ypsilon's):

```
error: attempt call non-procedure: (+ 1 2 3)

backtrace:
  0  (apply apply '(+ (1 2 3)))
  ..."/dev/stdin" line 1
```

What have I failed to understand?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem with `'(+ (1 2 3))` is that the `+` is quoted and thus interpreted as a symbol.

You would have to use `eval` to get a value for the `+` symbol.

In other words, what you are trying to do, is not going to work.

Edit: Another option is quasiquote. Eg:

```
(apply apply `(,+ (1 2 3))) ; => 6
```

Or (without quasiquote)

```
(apply apply (list + '(1 2 3))); => 6
```

Comment: Got it.  That should have been clear from the wording of the error.